# Sonar, cant see my hello world plugin

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I'm trying to get started with sonar plugin development. Ive started off by following this tutorial

http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=117899451

Ive built this hello world plugin and have copied the resulting jar (helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) to the /extensions/plugins directory.

I have rebuild the war. .//war/build-war.sh

The new war file is built. I then run sonar in standalone mode and browse to "Configuration > Settings" to try and view this plugin.... nothing. All the core plugs are there (Clover, Design....) but not my new hello world plugin.

There are no errors or relevant info in the logs. When I explore the new war file I can see that the helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar has been added to /WEB-INF/lib/

Any ideas?

I am using sonar-plugin-api version 1.10, my sonar instance is version 2.1.2. Could this be the issue?

I have no feedback from the sonar application at all, so im a little lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the tutorial is old. In the newest sonar (2.1.2), if a plugin doesnt have global configuration it will not appear in the settings.

This is what I started with,running the archetype will provide you with an up-to-date example plugin, it's worked fine for me:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Getting+started

And those tips have been really helpful going forward:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+plugin